# Countdown logic inside UICollectionViewCell subclass when reusing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` with custom cells where I want to display a countdown in some of them. The problem I am having is that when I have a cell with a countdown and scroll it down other cells which shouldn't have a countdown inside them is displaying a countdown as well.

I understand that this has to do with the reuse of the cells but not sure what I should do about it. Here is my code:

cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MainCell *cell = (MainCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MainCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(displayCountDown.boolValue){
            NSDate *endTime = [offer objectForKey:@"expiresDate"];
            [cell startTimer:endTime];
            cell.imgTimeLeftClock.hidden = NO;
}else{
            cell.lblTimeLeft.text = @"No time limit";
            cell.imgTimeLeftClock.hidden = YES;

}

return cell;

}
```

Inside MainCell.m:

```
- (void) startTimer :(NSDate *) endTime
{

        [self.timer invalidate];        

        self.startTime = [NSDate date];        
        self.endTime = endTime;

        double startTimeDouble = [self.startTime timeIntervalSince1970];
        int currentTimeRound = (int)startTimeDouble;

        double endTimeDouble = [self.endTime timeIntervalSince1970];
        int endTimeRound = (int)endTimeDouble;

        self.secondsLeft = endTimeRound - currentTimeRound;        

        // create a new timer
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(calculateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

        [self.timer fire];


}

- (void)calculateTimer
{

    self.secondsLeft--;

    if(self.secondsLeft > 0){
        int days = self.secondsLeft / 86400;
        int hours = (self.secondsLeft / 3600) %  24;
        int minutes = (self.secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
        int seconds = (self.secondsLeft %3600) % 60;

        self.lblTimeLeft.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", days, hours, minutes, seconds];
    }else{
        self.lblTimeLeft.text = @"Time's up";
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can do about this to have the countdown only displaying on the correct cells?

Answer (score 1):

You should use store the cell which are having timer in a array(namely timerArray) and use this array for adding timer to that cell or not as below,

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return collectionViewArray.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
MainCell *cell = (MainCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MainCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   if(displayCountDown.boolValue){
   //In place of this bool check you could simply check if that object(collectionViewArray) is in your timerArray.

   //Your timerArray will contain obj which are having timer in it and collectionViewArray is your array having all objects(with/without timer and is actual array that you use for count)      

   //Then if-else condition will go similarly.

        NSDate *endTime = [offer objectForKey:@"expiresDate"];
        [cell startTimer:endTime];
        cell.imgTimeLeftClock.hidden = NO;
   }else{
        cell.lblTimeLeft.text = @"No time limit";
        cell.imgTimeLeftClock.hidden = YES;

  }
 return cell;
}
```

Hope this help you out !

Answer (score 0):

Your logic in cellForItem is based around displayCountDown.boolValue but it should be based around the indexPath of the cell as well. So every time cellForItem is called you know which cell should show the label and when it should be hidden. You either switch it on or off based on the index path.
Otherwise like you say the collection view will reuse it.